# How To Make All Traffic To Go Through One Interface In Linux

Tags: linux, iptables, ip, route

I have a [self-written interface tun0](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/anticensority/bebkzB) ([TUN/TAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUN/TAP) based) that outputs what it receives.
I need all traffic of the system to flow through this interface.
The role of the interface is:

1. To figure out packets likely to be censored and tunnel them.
2. Pass all other traffic untouched.

As you guess I am trying to build an anticensorship tool.
Decision about tunneling must be taken inside tun0 process
because only there we may use trusted DNS.

I need your help to show me how to make all traffic flow through a self-written interface tun0. If tun0 needs changes I ask you to provide such changes.

Below is how I tried to make all traffic go through tun0 and failed (pings fail).

### Compiling

1. `gcc tun0.c`
2. `sudo ./a.out`

### Configuring

1. `sudo ip addr add 10.0.0.1/24 dev tun0`
2. create table John

   ```
   $ cat /etc/iproute2/rt_tables 
   #
   # reserved values
   #
   255     local
   254     main
   253     default
   0       unspec
   #
   # local
   #
   #1      inr.ruhep

   200 John
   ```

Order is important:

3. `sudo ip rule add from all lookup John`
4. `sudo ip route add default dev tun0 table John`
5. `sudo ip rule add iif tun0 lookup main priority 500`

   ```
   $ ip rule
   0:      from all lookup local 
   500:    from all iif tun0 lookup main 
   32765:  from all lookup John 
   32766:  from all lookup main 
   35000:  from all lookup default
   ```

#### Troubleshooting

1. `sudo tcpdump -i wlp2s0 -qtln icmp` and then `ping -I tun0 8.8.8.8` shows no packets captured, it means no packets are transmitted from tun0 to wlp2s0 via `iif tun0 lookup main` rule.
2. When I replaced `tun0` with `lo` everywhere then it worked for me.

#### Also Tried

1. Turning off reverse path filtering, `rp_filter=0` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`

#### Answer Troubleshooting

```
iptables -I FORWARD -j LOG --log-prefix "filter/FORWARD " 
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "nat/OUTPUT " 
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -j LOG --log-prefix "nat/PREROUTING " 
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -j LOG --log-prefix "nat/POSTROUTNG "
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

Modified sources from answer are also [here](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/anticensority/bebkzB).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So in your configuration, all the packets you try to send to the network initially originating from `10.0.0.1` (because they are going through `tun0` interface and its local address is `10.0.0.1`). You capture the packets, everything is fine so far.
Now, `tun0` sends the packets further. **Source address** is `10.0.0.1` and you want the packets to leave through a different interface (`wlp2s0` in your case). That's **routing** so let's enable routing first:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

After that, if you'll look at `tcpdump` for `wlp2s0` you can notice the packets leave with source address `10.0.0.1` and not with the source address of the wlan interface (what you would expect I guess). So we need to change the source address and it's called **source NAT**. In linux it's easy with help of *netfilter/iptables*:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlp2s0 -s 10.0.0.1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Please also check that your `FORWARD` chain has `ACCEPT` policy or you would need to **allow forwarding** with something like:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o wlp2s0 -s 10.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlp2s0 -o tun0 -d 10.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
```

Everything should work now: *linux kernel* does the routing, it's moving packets from `tun0` interface to `wlp2s0`. *netfilter* should change the source IP `10.0.0.1` to your `wlp2s0` interface assigned address for output packets. It memorizes all the connections and when the reply packets go back (if they) it changes the destination address of the `wlp2s0` interface assigned address to `10.0.0.1` (the "conntrack" feature).
Well, it should but it doesn't. It seems, *netfilter* gets confused with this complicated routing configuration and the fact that the same packet first goes through the `OUTPUT` chain and then being routed and comes to `PREROUTING` chain. At least on by Debian 8 box it doesn't work.
The best way to troubleshoot *netfilter* is the `TRACE` feature:

```
modprobe ipt_LOG
iptables -t raw -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j TRACE
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -p icmp -j TRACE
```

*I only enable tracing for ICMP packets, you may use other filter to debug.*
It will show what tables and chains the packet goes through. And I can see that the packet goes no further the `FORWARD` chain (and it's not being caught by the `nat/POSTROUTING` chain that actually does `SNAT`).
Below are several approaches to make this work.

### APPROACH #1

The best way to un-confuse *netfilter* is to change the source IP address of packets in `tun0.c` application. It's also the most natural way.
We need to **change 10.0.0.1 to 10.0.0.2** on the way outwards and **10.0.0.2 to 10.0.0.1** on the way back.
I've modified `tun0.c` with source address change code. [Here is the new file](https://pastebin.com/cdAvxYCe) and [here is patchfile](https://pastebin.com/2NTJJBFt) for your `tun0.c`. Changes to IP header also involve **checksum correction**, so I took some code from [OpenVPN project](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn).
Here is the full list of commands I execute after a clean reboot and  `tun0_changeip.c` launch:

```
ifconfig tun0 inet 10.0.0.1/30 up
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
ip route add default dev tun0 table John
ip rule add from all lookup John
ip rule add from 10.0.0.2 lookup main priority 500
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlp2s0 -s 10.0.0.2 -j MASQUERADE
```

Please note that you don't need to turn off the *reverse path filtering* in that case, because everything is legal - `tun0` only receives and sends packets that belong to its subnet. Also you can do a source-based routing instead of interface-based.

### APPROACH #2

It's possible to do `SNAT` before the packet reach `tun0` interface. It's not very correct though. You will definitely need to turn off the *reverse path filtering* in this case:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.tun0.rp_filter=0
# It won't work without also changing the "all" value
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0
```

Now, do `SNAT`:
    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -s 10.0.0.1 -j SNAT --to-source ip.address.of.your.wlan.interface

Here we change the source address just **before** the packets reach the `tun0` device. `tun0.c` code resend these packets "as is" (with changed source address) and they are successfully routed through wlan interface.
But you might have a dynamic IP on wlan interface and want to use `MASQUERADE` (in order to not specify the interface address explicitly). Here is how you can make use of `MASQUERADE`:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -s 10.0.0.1 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.55.1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlp2s0 -s 10.0.55.1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Please note the "`10.0.55.1`" IP address - it's different. You can use any IP here, it doesn't matter. The packets reach `nat/POSTROUTING` chain on `wlp2s0` interface if we change the source IP before. And now it's not dependent on a static IP for wlan interface.

### APPROACH #3

You can also use `fwmark`. That way you don't need `SNAT` but you'll capture only outgoing packets:
First we need to disable *reverse path filtering* for `tun0` because it will forward packets that belong to another network:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.tun0.rp_filter=0
# It won't work without also changing the "all" value
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0

Now let's alter the routing rules a bit:
# Delete old rules
ip rule del iif tun0 lookup main
ip rule del from all lookup John

# Packets will start going from wlan interface so they will have source address of it
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -o wlp2s0 -j MARK --set-mark 1
ip rule add fwmark 0x1 lookup John
```

That's another "hack" for *routing* and *netfilter* that works on my Debian 8 box, but still I recommend to take the first approach as it's more natural and doesn't use any hacks.

---

You may also consider to build your application as a **transparent proxy**. I think it would be much easier instead of analyzing packets from tun device.

Comment: I had to use `-j SNAT`, not `-s SNAT`

Comment: It works but performance is very intermittent (it may stall for a 10 of seconds then continue working). I'm going to figure why it happens and how to fix this.

Comment: Sorry it was my typo. I added another approach to my answer. Have no idea about the performance issue. By the way, why not to use a transparent proxy with iptables DNAT to filter and divert the traffic?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your mark approach, I've added only `sudo ip rule add iif tun0 lookup main priority 500` to it but still it did't work. I like this approach, pity that I can't reproduce it.

Comment: So far from three methods offered I managed to make work only one with MASQUERADE, but it stalls for non-response periods of 10s.

Comment: Transparent proxy is a very interesting topic, thank you for offering it.

Comment: Here is complete command list I issued in my clean debian jessie installation to test the fwmark approach: https://pastebin.com/RaYZP25y (I used two virtual terminals, one to run tun0 and another to issue commands). Didn't you forget the rp_filter when you were trying this approach? P.S. you don't need the "ip rule add iif tun0" in this scenario because packets going out from tun0 don't have the fwmark to they will reach main route table anyway.

Comment: Regarding transparent proxy, you can proxy DNS traffic as well, and modify/forward DNS answers as you wish. The DNS protocol is pretty simple, there are a lot of easy implementations in C and other languages.

Comment: I tried your commands from answer and from pastebin verbatim and still couldn't make fwmark work: https://pastebin.com/6jFXSW0s

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69508/discussion-between-tifssoft-and-ilyaigpetrov).

Comment: `packets leave with source address 10.0.0.1 and not with the source address of the wlan interface` -- why is this a problem? Doesn't gateway do the NAT and on the way back destination 10.0.0.1 should be handled fine?

Comment: It's not a problem it's just a requirement to do a SNAT before these packets reach WAN. Normally, iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlp2s0 -s 10.0.0.1 -j MASQUERADE does it. However doing NAT is just another job your computer does, so if it's possible to avoid this, it's better to avoid.

Comment: About your new solution -- could you, please, append it to the answer with links to modified source codes. Though I'm mostly engaged with the idea of writing a TCP proxy now, I think what you've done shouldn't be lost in vain.

Comment: I've finally updated my post. The new solution is the 1st approach. Please tell me if you find any mistakes or things you think need to be explained deeper. And thank you for the bounty, you made me really happy!

Comment: Thank you for your new approach, I followed it step by step and it worked perfectly. Yet I don't understand why we need to change ips, most importantly it works. In case my plans with TCP proxy fail I will be able to return to your answer. You showed a lot of networking skills here and I don't doubt your skills will be coveted. Good luck!